# Как синхронизировать маркеры в GoogleMap между пользователями?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация, android-location

Есть Google карта, каждый пользователь приложения может добавлять маркеры, как их синхронизировать с другими пользователями ? т.е. маркеры которые добавил один пользователь, отображались у других.

Comment: Юзер добавил маркер - он сохранился на сервере. Все остальные маркеры все юзеры берут с сервера. Т.е. вам нужен свой сервер. Можно попробовать firebase для этого. Но он теперь только для юр. лиц и платный в РФ

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Как раз и firebase и собираюсь использовать, но проблема в одном, если маркеров больше 2000 то при загрузке активити с картой, не будет ли слишком затратно загружать столько маркеров с сервера?

Comment: Лично я не знаю способа отобразить все данные не загрузив все данные. Можно, конечно, попробовать свой собственный сервер написать и как-то определять что локальные маркеры устарели и скачивать только новое